# Javascript variable to be printed on php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Can someone tell me what's wrong in this code?
I'm trying to print in php the javascript variable that i just gave a regex.
I am having this error Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).html is not a function

```
$.post('display.php', {postName:acceptedName, postEmail:acceptedEmail, postNum: acceptedContactNum, postAddress: acceptedAddress, postDept: acceptedDept},
        function(data){
            document.getElementById("display").html(acceptedName,acceptedEmail,acceptedContactNum,acceptedAddress,acceptedDept);
        });

<?php

$acceptedName = $_POST['postName'];
$acceptedEmail = $_POST['postEmail'];
$acceptedContactNum = $_POST['postNum'];
$acceptedAddress = $_POST['postAddress'];
$acceptedDept = $_POST['postDept'];

echo $acceptedName;
echo $acceptedEmail;
echo $acceptedContactNum;
echo $acceptedAddress;
echo $acceptedDept;

?>
```

Comment: Why making multiple POST requests? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ read this to send multiple data at once.

Comment: Please do not post your code as images. Just embed it here.

Comment: There should be an edit button below your question.

Comment: @mo2ph3u5 it's now modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesnt work because you don't do anything with the result of the php script in your javascript.

A Post example:

```
$.post("display.php", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

You need to declare a Javascript function for the return values of your PHP, data would be the PHP's echo. With Status you can get the status of the reqouest for example: `success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror`

**Edit:**

```
$.post('display.php', {
  "postName": acceptedName,
  "postName": acceptedName,
  "postEmail": acceptedEmail,
  "postNum": acceptedContactNum,
  "postAddress": acceptedAddress,
  "postDept": acceptedDept
}).done(function(data){

        document.getElementById("display").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: I still get an error of Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. the line of $.post('display.php'), {

Comment: do you have jquery included? post() is a jquery function

Comment: I'm just using javascript. coz im using document.getElementbyIDs

Comment: $ is a namespace for "jQuery". Instead of the $ you can also write jQuery.post. You will need to include jQuery in order to bring it to work like this

Comment: Ok, so now i imported the jquery.min.js file thing.. then turned out to be Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).html is not a function

Comment: use this `$("#display").html(data);`